# Ruby array of words

Tags: arrays, ruby

I was just working with array of words in ruby which I usually write like this:

```
%w(a b c)
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

And I came across a post in which I saw author using `%w||` instead of `%w()`. And then out of curiosity I tried following:

```
%w|a b c|
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

%w_a b c_
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

%w*a b c*
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

%w-a b c-
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]

%w+a b c+
#=> ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Also, same happened with array of symbols

```
%i|a b c|
#=> [:a, :b, :c]

%i_a b c_
#=> [:a, :b, :c]

%i*a b c*
#=> [:a, :b, :c]

%i-a b c-
#=> [:a, :b, :c]

%i+a b c+
#=> [:a, :b, :c]
```

**Is it something which is done intentionally?**

**Is there any difference in these formats or it's just for the convenience of programmers.**

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It makes it possible to input :

```
%w|a) b) c)|
#=> ["a)", "b)", "c)"]
```

In contrast :

```
%w(a) b) c))
```

is a SyntaxError :

```
SyntaxError: unexpected tIDENTIFIER, expecting end-of-input
```

It also works for strings :

```
%q|"](\/#{t}'?}|
#=> "\"](\\/\#{t}'?}"
```

Answer (score 3):

This is done intentionally by the language designers so you can have arbitrary strings in your array.
The syntax even considers certain "opening" vs. "closing" symbols as delimiters:

> If you are using “(”, “[”, “{”, “<” you must close it with “)”, “]”, “}”, “>” respectively. You may use most other non-alphanumeric characters for percent string delimiters such as “%”, “|”, “^”, etc.

You can read more about it in the [language documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.4.0/doc/syntax/literals_rdoc.html#label-Percent+Strings).